# How netstat is able to read route tables?

Tags: php, route, netstat

For my php containers if I need to detect the ip where ide listens to. I run:

```
ip=$(netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10)
```

And I get the gateway IP. But for that I need to install the `net-tools` or equivalent to the php application. Therefore I want to implement the nessesary functionality on my own (detect the gateway ip).

So how `netstat` and similar tools (eg. `route`) is able to read routing tables?

As far as I know at linux a routing table is generated but Idk where this table is stored.

Comment: Is `ip` installed in your container? It is a better supported tool compared to `netstat`.

Comment: No is is not and I do not want to. The issue is that I want my container to contain just the nessesary tools. So having a small code just just enough tools is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Perl offers a simple way to convert your data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$s = shift @ARGV or die "One argument expected\n";
@h = reverse unpack("A2A2A2A2", $s);
@i = map { hex($_) } @h;
print +(join ".", @i), "\n";
```

Written as a one-liner, with your data:

```
perl -e '$s=shift @ARGV;@h=reverse unpack"A2A2A2A2",$s;@i=map{hex }@h;print +(join".",@i),"\n"' 010016AC
172.22.0.1
```

The script takes the address to be converted as a command-line argument; unpacks it into four 2-character strings; reverses the order of the strings; converts each 2-characters to a decimal value and prints the sequence with a dot character between pair.

Comment: good if I wanted in my docker perl to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The `netstat` and any other command parted the route table from file `/proc/net/route`.

---

If making a script the ip is encoded as a Hex string with revese order for example the ip `172.22.0.1` is encoded as `010016AC` an easy wat to do this is to split the `010016AC` into 2 letter chunks into a table and do an opposite traversal. On each traverse convert the hex string into an integer.

In other words you need to do the following:

```
010016AC -> AC160001 -> AC.16.00.01 -> 172.22.0.1
```

For php script I used the following regex as well (with `preg_match`):

```
/^\w*\s(00000000)\s(\w*)/m
```

The second match (the group `(\w*)`) contains the gateway ip.